# Initialize properties when called or in __init__ in Python

Tags: python, properties

Is it better style to define private class variables in the __init__ method or in the getter? It seems like there is no need to define the variable until it is called.

Defining the variable in **init**:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if self._bar is None:
            self._bar = Bar()
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self._bar = value
```

Defining it in the getter:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def bar(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_bar'):
            self._bar = Bar()
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self._bar = value
```

Comment: What would defining them in the class definition look like?

Comment: Do you mean class attributes, or do you actually mean instance attributes?  Because `self._bar` is an instance attribute here, no a class attribute.

Comment: Doing a `self._bar = None` in `__init__()` _is_ defining it.

Comment: I mean instance attribute.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to define class attributes before you need them, at least not from interpreter perspective, but there is a huge gain as it vastly improves code readability. And for that you should just define them in class definition, not inside init.

Example of such definitions would be:

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

You can read up more in documentation http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: The OP was actually talking about instance attributes.  This doesn't apply in that case.

Answer (score -1):

For your particular example, both ways are overly conplicated. Try:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar()
```

Comment: This doesn't encapsulate the variable. Also, it uses the memory to create a new Bar before we find out if the bar attribute will even get called.

Comment: @travis1097 When you say it doesn't encapsulate the variable, do you mean it should be `self._bar = Bar()`?  Because otherwise it's not clear what you mean.